# how to pin a marker on static image in html java page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am displaying one static image using html/jsp/javascript. I am trying to pin a marker on the static image by using absolute and relative tags.

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img src="a.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
<img src="b.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px;"/>
</div>
```

The problem is when i zoom the image, marker remains on the screen at same 25px, 25px. How can i lock the marker on the image so that even after zooming or moving the image scroll bar, marker should move automatically along with the image.

with above code, it appears marker is locked on the screen, not on the static image.

Comment: How do you zoom? Using the browsers zoom function or are you resizing the image with javascript?

Comment: Normally your approach should be working... browser zooming should also effect your absolute positioning relative to the wrapper div

Comment: This might help - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Answer (score 0):

If you're only scrolling or zooming the image itself, the marker is unaffected and remains in place. Instead, try changing the entire `div` element containing both images.

For example, if you did something like this:

```html
<div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100; height: 100;">
  <!-- both images here -->
</div>
```

The containing `div` will gain scroll bars which move both images, keeping them aligned. (This will only take effect if the `div` is smaller than your main image, since there's no need for scroll bars otherwise.)

As for zooming / scaling: it depends on how you're doing it. If you're using the browser's zoom function, it should work no matter what. If you're applying some CSS to the image, applying that CSS to the `div` instead should do the trick. If you're resizing the image using javascript, you'll probably need to do some calculations to determine the marker's new position.